How do I rename an exported stdcall function from a dll and keep it possible to link to the library?
I want to hook win32 dll's, and make it possible to link to it. The DLL I want to hook exports stdcall function symbols without decorations. Renaming a symbol can be done using DEF definitions files.
The problem with this dll and import library is that the link library does not contain a "link" to the decorated symbol, which causes programs linking to it to fail with a undefined reference error.
Small reproducer that imitates ddraw.dll, which exports a DirectDrawCreate stdcall function in 32-bit x86. Remark that it does not have a @12 decoration)
dll.c
extern void __stdcall __declspec(dllimport) __declspec(dllexport) OutputDebugStringA(const char *);
extern long __stdcall DirectDrawCreate( void *guid, void **ddraw, void *outer);
long __stdcall DirectDrawCreate( void *guid, void **ddraw, void *outer) {
  OutputDebugStringA("Hello World!\n");
  /* Do other things */
  return 0;
}

dll.def
EXPORTS
    DirectDrawCreate=DirectDrawCreate@12

Build the dll as:
$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -shared dll.c dll.def -Wl,--out-implib,libmyddraw.dll.a -o ddraw.dll -lkernel32

user.c
extern long __stdcall DirectDrawCreate( void *guid, void **ddraw, void *outer);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  DirectDrawCreate(0, 0, 0);
  return 0;
}

Build the user executable as:
$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc /tmp/user.c libmyddraw.dll.a

The last command fails with:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/13.2.1/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccgCAKzJ.o:user.c:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `DirectDrawCreate@12'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Linking with -lddraw works. How can I fix my sources/build procedure?

Do you have the same problem if you remove extern from the declaration of DirectDrawCreate in dll.c (and optionally add __declspec(dllexport)), and then add __declspec(dllimport) to the declaration of DirectDrawCreate in user.c?

simply use EXPORTS
DirectDrawCreate

@RemyLebeau Linking will work, but the user executable will use DirectDrawCreate@12, whereas I want it to use DirectDrawCreate (as the original does). The executable is thus no longer compatible with the original ddraw.dll by MS.

@RbMm This has the same behavior as I described in my post: an undecorated DirectDrawCreate is exported from the dll (=good), but also an undecorated DirectDrawCreate is exported in the import library (=bad). This results in a undefined reference link error.

i dont know about mingw, never use it. but in case cl+link, if use EXPORTS DirectDrawCreate and EXTERN_C  DirectDrawCreate in src, exactly needed result for you - decorated in lib and undecorated in export

@maarten "an undecorated DirectDrawCreate is exported in the import library (=bad)). This results in a undefined reference link error" - then either you are not creating the import lib correctly, or you are not linking it into the exe correctly. For example, in the exe, try using -L. -lmyddraw instead of specifying libmyddraw.dll.a directly.

I managed to reproduce the behavior. Just out of curiosity, does the executable linked with libbddraw.a run (in Cmd)?

@RemyLebeau Passing the path of the import library using the filename is more precise then using -L and -l: you're not at the mercy of search paths. But I tried, and it has the same behavior as using the file name.

@CristiFati The executable can only be created when it uses DirectDrawCreate@12. This exe will run against my hooked ddraw.dll (if it exports the decorated symbol), but not against the ddraw.dll from the Windows operating system (which only exports an undecorated symbol).

Looking at how wine does it, I think it creates custom import libraries.
https://gitlab.winehq.org/wine/wine/-/blob/master/tools/winebuild/import.c?ref_type=heads#L1334
